# delphi 2009 unicode + ansi problem

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2009, isapi

I'm porting an isapi (pageproducers) application from delphi 7 to delphi 2009, the pages are based on html files in UTF8.

Everything goes well except when Onhtmltag is fired and I replace a transparent tag with any value with special characters like accented characters (áé...) Those characters are replaced in the output with an � character.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As part of your debugging procedure, you should go find out exactly what byte value(s) the browser receives for the question-mark character.

As you should know, Delphi 2009's string type is Unicode, whereas all previous version were ANSI. Delphi 7 introduced the `Utf8String` type, but Delphi 2009 made that type special. If you're not using that type for holding strings that are encoded as UTF-8, then you should start doing so. Values held in `Utf8String` variables will be converted to `UnicodeString` values automatically when you assign one to the other.

If you're storing your UTF-8-encoded strings in ordinary `AnsiString` variables, then they will be converted to Unicode using the default system code page if you assign them to a `UnicodeString`. That's not what you want.

If you're assigning UTF-8-encoded literals to variables of type `string`, stop that. That type expects its values to be encoded as UTF-16, just like `WideString` always has.

If you are loading your files into a `TStrings` descendant with `LoadFromFile`, then you need to start using that method's second parameter, which tells it what encoding to use. UTF-8-encoded files should use `TEncoding.UTF8`. The default is `TEncoding.Unicode`, which is little-endian UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks Rob, the last paragraph is exactly the solution for my problem.

Comment: Actually, it was Delphi 6 that introduced UTF8String.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a character encoding issue.

The Delphi IDE usually uses Windows-1252 or UTF-16 to encode source code.
HTML often uses UTF-8.

You probably need some transliteration between those encodings.
For that you need to find out what encodings are used exactly (like [Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33732/rob-kennedy) mentions).

Or revert to HTML escaping accented characters (like [Ralph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3724/ralph-rickenbach) mentions)

Can you post a small app that shows the problem? (you can email me, about anything that has jeroen in the username and pluimers.com in the domain name will arrive in my mailbox).

--jeroen

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, after some test the problem was very very simple (or stupid also)

```
response.contenttype := 'text/html charset=UTF-8'
```

No need to translate manually between unicodestring utf8string ansistring widestring. Delphi 2009 string usage is near to perfect.